# Override Django queryset update method

Tags: django, django-models, overriding, audit-logging, django-simple-history

I want to override Django Queryset **Update** method , to log the model changes in another table.I have override the method , but not able to find the id's of the rows which are going to get update.I am getting the fields which are getting changed from **kwargs**
I'm using Django v1.9.5.
I went through the docs of **django-simple-history** and **django-reversion** , but they don't log changes on **update** method.

```
class PollQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # save data into other table whose schema is 
        #(model_name,field_name,model_pk_id,old_value,new_value)

        super().update(*args, **kwargs)

class ModelWithCustomManager(models.Model):
    objects = PollQuerySet.as_manager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding the `update` method, your may want to look in to [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/). On `pre-save` and `post-save` you can grab data from the model and save it into a log table.

Comment: The [update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update) method of the QuerySet does not emit any signal.

Comment: UPDATE method does not emit any signal....that's why I want to override it.